# Get Departments and use them in a combobox MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, enums, moss, web-parts

Anyone knows how to do this?

I need to get all the "Departments" from MOSS 2007 and 
use them in the editable properties of a webpart...

My only idea how to solve this would be by getting the departements
in the constructor of my webpart and writing it to an enum using reflection,
but maybe that's to complicated or impossible to do.

Thanks,

Ruben

Comment: What is departments? where do you get them from?

Comment: If you go to SharePoint Central Administration -> Shared Services Administration -> "SharedServices1" (on my pc) -> Users Profiles and properties -> view user profiles  -> edit a user -> Property "Department"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to create a custom ToolPart in your webpart.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850306/sharepoint-webpart-combobox-of-lists) and the [tutorial on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178%28office.11%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article explaining a very creative way of getting a list of departments for a given site. from this you could easily give the end users the option via a public enum down the path you initially started.

http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/using-the-keywordquery-class-to-get-a-list-of-departments/

Comment: Is there also a way of getting the property "Show to" next to the department on the User Profile???

Comment: using the logic from the link I posted you could return both the departments and the show to properties. I'vee never used show to but i'd imagine it's very much along the same lines.