# Can I use files as custom SharePoint WebPart property?

Tags: sharepoint, properties, web-parts

Is it possible to use a file as custom SharePoint Webpart property? I would like to provide a file upload box in the WebPart editing menu. ("Modify This Web Part" -> "Custom Properties").

According to the documentation ([MSDN - Creating a Web Part with Custom Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28v=office.11%29.aspx)) by default only bool, int, string, enum and datetime types are supported.

Is there any way to allow the user to upload a file instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom EditorPart (or Toolpart) that allows the user to upload a file. I like Bil Simser's blog because he helps mimic out of the box SharePoint styles:
http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2009/08/12/spreading-some-sharepoint-love-to-editorpart.aspx

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850306/sharepoint-webpart-combobox-of-lists/2859684#2859684) of someone who also needed a Toolpart and the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178%28office.11%29.aspx).